# Spring jpa Exception - Found shared references to a collection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

#### Exception

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Found shared references to a collection: lk.pwc.projects.rdd.rims.entitymanagement.domain.common.Land.deedList; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: lk.pwc.projects.rdd.rims.entitymanagement.domain.common.Land.deedList
```

#### Snippet Causing the issue

```java
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "land_application_upload_deed", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "land_application_id"))
    private Set<LandDeed> deedList;
```

Above Mapping throwing the error

Answer (score 2):

This thing happened whenever you reinitialize your collection property. In your case, it is "deedList". Instead of reinitializing it, just clear it and add new elements in it.

Comment: This problem coming recursively mapping what to do that?